DAX: SubTotal Split by different Categories
I have to analyse the time each member of our IT group spends on solving Tickets. While the first column displays the total for each member on all Categories (this is the one I get correctly), the next columns should display the total of time each member spent on the different Categories.
member   TotalTime   Tickets_ERP   Tickets_Report  Tickets_SQL  Tickets_Other
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
John       80           15            0              55           10
Mary      120           85           35               0            0
Peter      90           25           60               0            5

I created the measure
TotalTime = SUM(Tickets[workingTimeMinutes])

and dragged members and TotalTime into a Matrix. So far so good. How do I need to define the SubTotals for the different Categories? I can't make it work.
This is what I tried:
Tickets_ERP = CALCULATE(SUM(Tickets[workingTimeMinutes]),Tickets[Category]="ERP")

I kind of understand that I need to build a SUMX on row basis where I sum up based on the condition, but can't make the syntax work.

ChatGPT helped me to get the solution:
Tickets_ERP = CALCULATE(SUM(Tickets[workingTimeMinutes]),Filter(Tickets,Tickets[Category]="ERP"))


could you pls provide some sample data and what's the expected output for Ticket_ERP?

Sorry, but I wouldn't know how to provide the data. The expected output for Ticket_ERP would be the column as described in my example: Group data for the three members with (15/85/25) while I get (125/125/125)

Using the mock data at the bottom of this post, I was able to replicate the expected output using the following measures.
TotalTime:
TotalTime = SUM(Tickets[WorkingTimeMinutes])

Tickets_ERP:
Tickets_ERP = CALCULATE(SUM(Tickets[WorkingTimeMinutes]), Tickets[Category] = "ERP")

Tickets_Report:
Tickets_Report = CALCULATE(SUM(Tickets[WorkingTimeMinutes]), Tickets[Category] = "Report")

Tickets_SQL:
Tickets_SQL = CALCULATE(SUM(Tickets[WorkingTimeMinutes]), Tickets[Category] = "SQL")

Tickets_Other:
Tickets_Other = CALCULATE(SUM(Tickets[WorkingTimeMinutes]), Tickets[Category] = "Other")

Output:



Member
TotalTime
Tickets_ERP
Tickets_Report
Tickets_SQL
Tickets_Other




John
80
15
0
55
10


Mary
120
85
35
0
0


Peter
90
25
60
0
5



Mock Data:
Members Table



MemberID
MemberName




1
John


2
Mary


3
Peter



Tickets Table



TicketID
MemberID
Category
WorkingTimeMinutes




1
1
ERP
15


2
1
SQL
55


3
1
Other
10


4
2
ERP
85


5
2
Report
35


6
3
ERP
25


7
3
Report
60


8
3
Other
5



Relationship: 1 to Many, Members[MemberID] to Tickets[MemberID]
